# Dynamic page title in views from a field of a node passed in url filter

Tags: 8, views

I got a view of a content type 'A'.

I got relationships to another content type 'B'. Say 'B' has fields x, y, z

I have a contextual filter that gets a value from URL and filter such that B.x == value from url.

I could successfuly override the page title by the value of x by writing `{{ arguments.x }}`

Is it possible to overwrite the view page title to be B.y ??

Another question is about the breadcrumb, it is not affected by the override and always show the static page title. Is there a way to fix that?

I am currently using 8.3 alpha1 although I've been trying this on 8.2.5 as well.

Comment: Click on title and put `{{ field_y }}`

Comment: I tried that before but always empty.

Comment: long shot, try `{{ field_y|striptags }}`

Comment: No still empty. Just double checking, you meant to put that in the title field and not in the contextual filter - override title field, right? Anyway I tried both and didn't work.

Comment: No, I meant on the title of the view (the one above the FORMAT section)